# How to combine AND and multiple OR conditions in where clause

Tags: php, sql, laravel, where-clause, query-builder

I need to create this kind of sql query in Laravel:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `list` WHERE `column_A` > 100 AND (`column_B` = 'value_1' OR `column_B` = 'value_2' OR `column_B` = 'value_3' OR ... `column_B` = 'value_n')
```

The thing is that I need the second part of the condition (following after "AND") to be inserted as an array containing the conditions, i.e.:

```php
$conditions = array(['column_B', '=', 'value_1'], ['column_B', '=', 'value_2'], ['column_B', '=', 'value_3']), ['column_B', '=', 'value_n']);
```

so I can create each set of conditions separately.

Is there such a way to do this in Laravel Query Builder (no Eloquent please)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to group conditions you have to use a closure, you can read more here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#or-where-clauses

```
\DB::table('list')
    ->where('column_A', '>', 100)
    ->where(function($q) use ($conditions) { 
        foreach ($conditions as $condition) { 
            $q->orWhere(...$condition); 
        }  
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! That works perfectly! However I am a little bummed out with the "..." operator or whatever it is (never came across this before).

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to check one column against multiple values you can simply use `whereIn`:

```php
->where('column_A', '>', 100)
->whereIn('column_B', ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
```

Comment: That works as well. Thanks!